# Does NSwag convert DateTime to DateTimeOffset in the timezone the server is in?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, nswag

An application passes in `DateTime` values to an API where NSwag converts those to `DateTimeOffset` objects.
The auto-generated clients have to choose `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` for all `Datetime` properties across all objects in a project. So we went with `DateTimeOffset` in this scenario.

If a `DateTime` is passed to the API, does NSwag convert to the value to the timezone the server is operating in?

In other words, does the value change based on the server location of the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior depends on a few different factors in the web API and consuming service, none of which are specific to NSwag per se.

For reference, let's say `Service A` is the ASP.NET Core API where NSwag is configured and has a model

```cs
public class Person
{
    public DateTime FavoriteDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

NSwag is configured to generate C# client code using `DateTimeOffset` for `DateType` and `DateTimeType` settings (the [default](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/v13.16.0/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/CodeGeneration/OpenApiToCSharpCommandBase.cs#L150-L176)) and produces a DTO like

```cs
public class Person
{
    public DateTimeOffset FavoriteDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

`Service B` consumes the NSwag-generated client code to make HTTP requests to `Service A`.

### Short Answer

Generally speaking, yes, the value will be converted to a `DateTime` in the local time zone of the web server (or container) hosting the API. This applies when:

- `Service B` has a C# class with a `DateTimeOffset` property serialized to construct an HTTP request body using the default serialization settings for the `Newtonsoft.Json` library and
- `Service A` has a model with a `DateTime` property and either the `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json` input formatter is used with default settings to bind the model from the HTTP request body

### Detailed Explanation

The exact behavior depends on the format of the string serialized into the HTTP request body from the `DateTimeOffset` property in `Service B` and the JSON body deserialization configuration in `Service A`.

#### Service B configuration

[NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/) uses [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/), which has `Newtonsoft.Json` as the default library for JSON serialization and deserialization ([reference](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/v10.7.1/src/NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp/CSharpGeneratorSettings.cs#L36)), as opposed to [System.Text.Json](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/v10.7.1/src/NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp/CSharpJsonLibrary.cs).

With the default `Newtonsoft.Json` serialization settings, a serialized HTTP request body may look like:

```cs
{
    "FavoriteDateTime": "2022-05-26T18:05:23.123-04:00"
}
```

However, the serialized string format may be different if the settings have been customized with a process like this:

1. Configure NSwag with `GenerateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod` as `false` and implement a `protected` method `UpdateJsonSerializerSettings` in the class named by `ClientBaseClass` setting. Alternatively, set `GenerateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod` to `true` and implement the `UpdateJsonSerializerSettings` for each specific `XyzClient` class in a separate file from the generated one using a partial class. Configure [CSharpClientGeneratorSettings](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CSharpClientGeneratorSettings) in `nswag.json`.
2. In the `UpdateJsonSerializerSettings` method, set `JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString` to a custom value. See [JsonSerializerSettings Properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm).

Since `DateFormatString` is used for serialization and deserialization, I don't recommend changing the `DateFormatString` setting for the generated client (unless you also change how `Service A` outputs date/time values in the HTTP response to match) but it is a setting that can impact how the value is parsed by `Service A`.
For example, a string like `"2022-05-26T22:05:23.123Z"` (if the time value is in UTC) deserializes to a `DateTime` with a UTC value (with `Kind=Utc`) rather than being converted to the `Service A` local time zone (with `DateTime.Kind=Local`).

#### Service A configuration

[ASP.NET Core input formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#input-formatters), rather than NSwag, are responsible for parsing the HTTP request body to bind the C# model properties.

Two primary options for input formatters handling JSON body data are:

1. `Newtonsoft.Json` (also known as [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)), which was the default for ASP.NET Core up through 2.2 and is still [supported up through at least ASP.NET Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support)
2. `System.Text.Json`, which became the [default option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-6.0#new-json-serialization) starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0

With the default deserialization settings of either input formatter and `Service A` running on a server whose time zone is set to US Central Time, `Service A` will parse the request value `"2022-05-26T18:05:23.123-04:00"` (US Eastern Daylight Time) and bind it to `Person.FavoriteDateTime` as a `DateTime` with `Kind=Local` (local server time) and a time component of `17:05:23.123`. Serializing this value would produce `"2022-05-26T17:05:23.123-05:00"` (US Central Daylight Time).

However, if the `Newtonsoft.Json` `JsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling` is set to `Utc` by configuring the `options` with `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`, then `Service A` will bind `Person.FavoriteDateTime` as a `DateTime` with `Kind=Utc` and a time part value of `22:05:23.123`. Serializing this value would produce `"2022-05-26T22:05:23.123+00:00"` (UTC time).

It does not appear that `System.Text.Json` has a built-in equivalent to `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `DateTimeZoneHandling` per the [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#specify-date-format).

**NOTE:** This answer focuses on input formatters, which [only handle binding the HTTP request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to a model. The behavior may be different for ASP.NET Core API action methods that bind an individual `DateTime` parameter from other sources than the HTTP request body (query string parameters, route data, etc.).

### Recommendation

To prevent subtle bugs, you may want to avoid any timezone conversions so that your HTTP request date/time value is available verbatim in the ASP.NET Core model.
To do this, consider using `DateTimeOffset` (rather than `DateTime`) for all source model properties in `Service A`, if feasible.